# Клюшка, ключ — этимология

Tags: этимология

Можно ли отнести слова "клюшка" и "ключ" к этимологически однокоренным?

Answer (score 2):

**[КЛЮШКА](http://www.endic.ru/rusethy/Kljushka-1087.html)**

> Искон. Суф. производное от *клюка* «клюшка, посох, палка с изогнутым
>   концом»; *чк > шк*, ср. *городошник < городочник*.

**[КЛЮЧ](http://www.endic.ru/rusethy/Kljuch-1-1083.html)**

> (1) (родник). Общеслав. Суф. производное (суф. *-j-, kj > ч*) от той
>   же основы, что *клюкать* «клокотать, бурлить».

**[КЛЮЧ](http://www.endic.ru/rusethy/Kljuch-2-1084.html)**

> (2) (для запора и отпирания). Общеслав. Суф. производное (суф. *-j-,
>   kj > ч*) от той же основы, что и *клюка* «клюшка, посох, палка с
>   загнутым концом», лат. *clavis* «ключ», нем. *Schloß* «замок» (см.
>   слесарь). *Ключ* исходно — «кривая, изогнутая палка». См. *случай,
>   приключение.*

Этимология по [Фасмеру](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87):

> Происходит от праслав. *ključь, от кот. в числе прочего произошли:
>   ст.-слав. ключь, русск. ключ, болг. ключ, укр. ключ, сербохорв. кљу̑ч
>   (род. п. кљу́ча) «крюк, ключ», словенск. ključ, чешск. klič, словацк.
>   kľuč, польск. klucz, в.-луж. kluč, н.-луж. kluc. Родственно индоевроп.
>   skl-; балт. словам, приведенным на клюка́, а также греч. κληΐς, дор.
>   κλᾱίς, κλάξ «ключ», κλείω «запираю»; лат. clāvus «гвоздь», clāvis
>   «ключ», claudō «запираю», ирл. cló (мн. clói) «гвоздь»; др.-в.-нем.
>   slioʒan «запирать», sluʒʒil «ключ», др.-сакс. slutil.

Можно говорить об историческом - этимологическом - родстве слов "клюшка" и "ключ"; сейчас они не относятся к однокоренным.